# jQueryUI autocomplete+Combobox widget is focused when hitting return on other elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I use the jqueryUI autocomplete + Combobox widget in a form with multiple inputs.

When i tab to a checkbox and hit return, i get instant focus on the combobox generated input element. This happens on every input element but not on selects.

How can i avoid this?

http://jsfiddle.net/cLxkyd1r/

(tab to second checkbox hit return)

code:

```
<form id="filterForm">
    <input type="checkbox" value="abc">
    <input type="checkbox" value="abc">
    <input type="checkbox" value="abc">
    <input type="checkbox" value="abc">
    <input type="checkbox" value="abc">
    <select class="combobox">
        <option value="1">123</option>
        <option value="2">ASDF</option>
        <option value="3">Max</option>
        <option value="4">Pain</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use e.preventDefault() or return false in order to prevent this default behavior:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').keydown(function(e){

if(e.keyCode == 13) {

    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $(this).prop('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh"); 
    } else {
         $(this).prop('checked', true);   
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: this stops the autofocus but also prevents all normal return events from working (checking) or on text fields send.